# Galois Basic Question (Cyclic Order 4 Extension of Q cannot contain i)

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$, where $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic of order 4. Show that $i\notin K$.

($i$ is the imaginary number $i^2=-1$.)

My Galois theory is quite weak, hope someone can check if my attempt is correct.

---

My attempt:

Suppose to the contrary $i\in K$. Let $\sigma\in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$.

Note that $\sigma (i)\sigma(i)=\sigma(i^2)=\sigma(-1)=-1$ since $\sigma$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$.

This means that $\sigma(i)=i$ or $\sigma(i)=-i$. The first case is ruled out since $\sigma$ only fixes $\mathbb{Q}$.

So $\sigma(i)=-i$. This means that $\sigma(a+bi)=a-bi$, so $\sigma$ is effectively complex conjugation, which has order 2.

Since $\sigma$ was arbitrary, this contradicts that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ has an element of order 4.

---

Is this ok?

Thanks.

Update: Now I see that my argument is clearly flawed. What would be the correct proof?

Comment: How did you conclude that $\sigma(a)=a$ for all $a\in K\cap \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right. I see the problem now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(fleshing this out now that OP worked out the details themself)

Because $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois and complex conjugates share a minimal polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$, we see that the complex conjugate of any element of $K$ is also an element of $K$. Therefore complex conjugation, call it $\sigma$, is an element of the Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(K/\Bbb{Q})$.

Assume contrariwise that $i\in K$. Because $\sigma(i)=-i$ and $\sigma^2=1_G$,
we can conclude that $\sigma$ is of order two. As $G$ is assumed to be cyclic,
$H=\langle\sigma\rangle$ is the only subgroup of index two in $G$. By Galois
correspondence the fixed field $M:=K^H=K\cap\Bbb{R}$ is the only quadratic intermediate field $\Bbb{Q}\subset M\subset K$.

But $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ would also be a quadratic intermediate field contradicting the above. Hence $i\notin K$.

Comment: I deleted this because I got a deja vu -vibe. Didn't find it right away, so undeleting. Stay tuned...

Comment: [This old answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/427499/11619) is related, but I still think there is an exact match somewhere... May be I just imagined it and the linked question was the one I associated this with. Giving up the search for now.

Comment: Oh, this is much simpler than what I did.  I suppose I'll leave my approach in case anyone finds it of interest.

Comment: I can see Q(i) is a quadratic extension because of the minimal polynomial of $i$ is $x^2+1$. Why is $K\cap\mathbb{R}$ quadratic?

Comment: Then I suppose we use the fact that the  cyclic group have unique subgroup of order 2, together with Galois Fundamental Theorem to get a contradiction.

Comment: I see why: $K\cap\mathbb{R}$ is the fixed field of complex conjugation which generates a subgroup of order 2.

Comment: @yoyostein: That's correct, well done! You do need to also show that $K$ is stable under complex conjugations to use the fact that complex conjugation is an automorphism of $K$, but that is routine .

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

This argument is not correct.  All you've shown is that the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ cannot have order $4$.  But the case that $\sigma(i)=-i$ is (a priori) possible even if $\sigma$ has order $4$: in this case, you just would conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is the fixed field of $\sigma^2$.  This doesn't (obviously) mean that $\sigma^2$ is the identity on all of $K$.

Here is a sketch of a correct argument.  We must have $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{a})$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Q}(i)$ that is not a square.  In order for this $K$ to be Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt{\overline{a}}$ must also be in $K$.  Writing down explicitly what an element of $K$ looks like, you can show that this can only happen if $a=b^2c$ for some $b\in\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and some $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ (this is the hard step; at the moment I don't see a way to prove it without using unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$).  But then $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{c})$ can be shown to have Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$, not $\mathbb{Z}/4$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slick solution, I think. Consider generally a cyclic extension $F/k$ and try to embed it in an over-extension $K/F/k$ such that $K/k$ is cyclic. For simplification, suppose that $F/k$ has degree $p^n$, $K/F$ has degree $p$ and $k$ contains a primitive $p$-th root $\zeta$ of unity ($p$ a prime). Then, using Kummer theory, it can be shown that $K$ exists iff $\zeta$ is a norm in $F/k$ (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691332/300700, where the situation is a bit more general). In our particular case here, $p=2$, $\zeta=-1$, $K/\mathbf Q$  is the given cyclic extension of degree 4. If $K$ contained $i$, take $F=\mathbf Q(i)$. Then $-1$ would be a norm in $F/\mathbf Q$, i.e. would be a sum of two squares in $\mathbf Q$ : impossible. Note that here, the previous embeddability criterion can be shown directly.

Comment: +1 Nice. However Kummer theory is beyond my reach at the moment.

Comment: Let's say that Kummer's theory describes "explicitly" the abelian extensions of exponent n of a field of characteristic not dividing n and containing a primitive n-th root of unity. The limits of the theory lie in the latter condition. Class field theory describes all the abelian extensions of a global field ( = number field or function field in prime characteristic) without this condition.

Comment: Kummer theory describes explicitly the abelian extensions of exponent n of a field F of characteristic prime to n, and containing a primitive n-th root of unity. For instance, in our case here, K is obtained by adjoining to F a p-th root of an element in F*. The limits of the theory are lying in the condition on the presence of adequate roots of 1. Class field theory dispenses with this, i.e. it describes all the abelian extensions, but only for global fields ( = number fields or function fields of prime characteristic).